# Как вызвать функцию фрагмента из активити?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

По нажатию на пункт меню ("три точки") функция должна заполнить поля в фрагменте. Все функции вынесены в отдельный файл.
Как это сделать или исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Активити хостит фрагменты, соответственно имеет возможность получить ссылку на любой свой фрагмент и вызвать его метод. Как именно уже зависит от вашего конкретного проекта.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja , подскажите как получить ссылку на этот фрагмент и вызвать его метод

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751537/5479247

Comment: А почему не обработать меню в самом фрагменте?

Comment: сама по себе проблема вызова функции решается через "фрагмент-менеджер" (чтобы из активити обратиться к фрагменту), но происходит ошибка инициализации полей, потому что активити получается на первом плане, а фрагмент с полями ещё не инициализировался....

Answer (score -1):

```
            id.action_do_it -> {
            val myFragment = FirstFragment()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, myFragment , "MyFragment")
                .commit()
            myFragment.date1.setText("30.04.2018")
            myFragment.date2.setText("09.06.2021")
            myFragment.date3.setText("30.03.2019")
            myFragment.date4.setText("22.04.2019")
            true
        }
```

осталось решить проблемы с инициализацией полей, так как в момент обращения к текстовым полям они ещё не инициализированы (команда в активити)

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Во-первых, редактируйте вопрос, чтобы дополнить подробностями, а поле ответа оставьте для ответов. Во-вторых, если вы создаёте новый фрагмент, то данные передают в таких случаях через аргументы

Comment: Из изначального вопроса делается вывод что фрагмент уже там есть, его только надо заполнить, тогда зачем вы еще один по клику в меню создаете? Или все-таки вопрос неверно сформулирован?